# Reduce API Calls From AngularJS Application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api

I am creating a simple web app that queries a service's API. There is a API call limit, meaning if I call too much it stops working. How can I reduce my api calls, but still display data in between those calls on a live refreshing page?

EDIT: To clarify, by "stops working" I mean there is a maximum amount of requests I am allowed to make within a timeframe. I want to cache the data, call once a minute, and live refresh.

Comment: What do you mean by "it stops working" when referring to the API?

Comment: Meaning there is a max quota per timeframe. I apologize for not being clear.

Comment: I would leverage the angular $interval service.  Documentation is here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval

Comment: But that wont cache the data. So if someone new visits the site, it will still query again.

Comment: You could use https://lodash.com/docs#debounce, this will return last result if invoked before given time.

Comment: @DevinStokes - the func that gets called in $interval would need to "cache" the data in a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

Store the returned data in a variable, check if the variable is already populated and if it is do not make the API call. If it is not populated then make the call to the API. If you are going to call refresh every minute then there is no way around this though... if you are calling it every minute there is no way to reduce the calls to less than 60 per hour.

If your concern is currently with testing/developing you could capture the returned data and set up a SoapUI project with the captured requests and server them to the application from there so that you don't chew up all your request limit.

If you are calling the endpoint via AJAX then your refresh will be async and the pages data will not change until your bound data changes in the Angular model object I'm assuming you have bound to your UI.

I would suggest putting up some of your code in order for a more specific answer to be posted.

Comment: I don't seem to be conveying the correct point. I will try to explain once more. I need a backend service to store the data (local). Such as Node. I was hoping to find a resource that could show me how to do this. So if there are 100 people visiting the site, only one query is made every 60 seconds. And after 60 seconds, refresh.

Comment: I get what you are saying now. You could build it in Node, although I have actually written a service/backend very similar to this in Java/Spring Framework.

What kind of infrastructure do you have available and what languages are you most comfortable with. Basically you will want to set up a REST endpoint that your service will call, in turn that endpoint will be running a process and refreshing its model every minute. Your app will call YOUR backend and you will have a service within that backend that will have a model based on the information attained from your API calls every minute

Comment: To do this I would create a model which aligns with my API data that is being returned and create a looped function that has a timer for 1 minute (you could use a thread sleep in a language like Java) and after this call the function to update your models values, and repeat...

The endpoint your app will call will just return a JSON version of the model from your backend which is exactly the same format as what you are currently doing. Therefore the only thing you will change in the front end is the endpoint address to point to your backend and not the external API

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Do you have any resources available I could take a look at with regard to this?

Comment: What language are you wanting to write it in? If Node is what you would like to do it in I don't have any examples but would be more than happy to find one that is similar to the solution I proposed above